# Simple downwards facing bar chart (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, bar-chart

Im stuck on what feels like a simple issue. I need to supply a list of numbers eg. [1,2,3,4,5] and the program should return a bar chart facing downwards for each value using "#" as the bar chart units.

[3,2,4] would become:

```
# # #
# # #
#   #
    #
```

in the console.

Ive tried creating a nested loop to print # as many times as needed per the list value.

```
def barChart(numbers):
    for i in numbers:
        for z in range(i):
            print("#")
```

but I've obviously gone wrong somewhere. could I get some guidance?

Comment: It's not actually a simple issue, because `print()` writes from left to right so you end up with 3, 2, 4 hashtags per line instead of per column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it. We need to keep re-scanning the list to determine if we have any more `#` to print per line. We terminate once all of the numbers are exhausted. In the case that one value is exceeded, we need to fill that character position with an empty space.

```
def bar_chart(numbers):
    row_count = 0
    keep_going = True

    while keep_going:
        row = ''.join(['#' if item > row_count else ' ' for item in numbers])
        print(row)
        row_count += 1
        if '#' not in row:
            keep_going = False

a = bar_chart([3, 2, 4])
```

Which gives:

```
###
###
# #
  #
```

Comment: Great! I really like this solution, I didn't realise the way to solve this was to scanning the list for the amount of "#" per line. I was trying to calculate each column all at once.

As a sidenote, could you use while True and then use 'break' if the final if statement returns True to end the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use third-party modules, something like pandas could be really useful:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> def bar_chart(numbers):
...     max_num = max(numbers)
...     result = {num: ['#'] * num + [''] * (max_num - num) for num in numbers}
...     result_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result)
...     return result_df
... 
>>> numbers = [3, 2, 4]
>>> print(bar_chart(numbers))
   3  2  4
0  #  #  #
1  #  #  #
2  #     #
3        #
```

That way, you also easily get the corresponding number above, if you like (although that's certainly possible in other methods described here).

Note: this also only handles positive integers in [0, inf]. Negatives aren't handled.